# find and replace if 2 columns are the same

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this table, if cell in column P matches cell in column V, replace Q cell with value from column W.

[image]

I found this vba script, but doesn't do what I really need I cant figure out how to edit it.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1873-excel-find-and-replace-multiple-values-at-once.html

Can you help me ?

Comment: If you want to avoid VBA; in a new cell use: `=IF(P1 = V1, W1, Q1)`

Comment: You're really just from ExtendOffice and want everyone to click on your link, aren't you?

Comment: @AlyAbdelaziz I'll try and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @Jeeped right .. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Substi_toot()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If Cells(i, "P") = Cells(i, "V") Then Cells(i, "Q") = Cells(i, "W")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The script works great but only if columns P and V are in the same row. I have a big list of sku and old prices, the other column is the new price and the sku for the specific product. Can you help me to ?

Comment: Ok I got it.

Sub Substi_toot()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        For t = 1 To N
        If Cells(t, "A") = Cells(i, "H") Then Cells(t, "B") = Cells(i, "I")
        Next t
    Next i
End Sub